# How to export data from umbraco CMS?

Tags: sql-server, umbraco

I have a project which is using umbraco cms, ie. MSSQL (Now we are rebuilding the site in WordPress). Which i cannot understand the relations. It's difficult in Umbraco. So i would like to download/Export the content directly from Umbraco CMS. But in cms i don't find any option to export the bulk data. Is any other way to do this? Or if you can help me to find any free tools. Or any free tools that can do MSSQL to MySQL simply?

Thanks In Advance / Rajeev

Comment: am not sure how you will manage if the whole data is migrated from MSSQL to MySQL?. Also in umbraco data in each content node is saved in an xml format, So how you are going to manage these data..?

Comment: Yeah. that's it. it saved in to xml format. So we have done it through xml fetching and findout the nodes. Thanks Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to explore using Umbraco's Courier add-on:

http://umbraco.com/products/more-add-ons/courier-2.aspx

It's not free, but it seems like it's the only tool in the market for this type of job.

Comment: @RajeevPrabhakaranNair: Share the steps how you did it!

Comment: @RajeevPrabhakaranNair Please share your knowledge

Answer (score 13):

You can do this by creating a package. In the Developer section of Umbraco, expand the Packages node and right-click on 'Created packages' and click 'Create'. Click on the package and in the 'Package Contents' tab of the editor you can select a content node with an option to include all of its child nodes.

[image: Umbraco content packaging]

Complete the required fields in the 'Package Properties' tab. Once you've pressed 'Save & Publish' you will be given the option to download the package.

[image: Download Umbraco package]

You can now download your content in this package and install it on another instance of Umbraco by using the 'Install local package' option.

More detailed instructions for this approach are available [here](http://www.uquickstart.com/umbraco-tips-and-tools/package-up-your-umbraco-website).

Comment: this could be OK, if you want to export just one content node.... but if you ahave several sites (a lot of) this aoucld be a little more complicated

Comment: When using Umbraco 7 the option is "Choose" a content node. The key thing above is to understand you need to Choose the content node you're after to download the associated data. If that content node already exists a duplicate node will be created and you'll have to modify\delete them as necessary. I haven't tried it but I believe you can Choose multiple nodes. A package.xml file is wrapped in the zip produced and would need to be processed somehow for import into Wordpress.